# Updating contact from unsubscribe to subscribe

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, unsubscriber

New to Marketing Cloud, the organization is not yet hooked up to salesforce--how would I update(automated) contacts who previously unsubscribed but now has opted in.

Comment: If my answer helped, please accept it, so others can see that this is the correct way to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it fits your use case you could set the subscribers status to "Active" via the Web Service API (SOAP-API).

More information can be found here: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/managing_subscriber_status_for_one_or_all_lists/